# О какой (?) к чёрту (?) справедливости речь?

Tags: пунктуация, члены-предложения

*Какая справедливость? О какой (?) к чёрту (?) справедливости речь?*

Чем в предложении является **к чёрту**? Нужно ли выделять его какими-то знаками?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Какая справедливость? О какой к  чёрту справедливости речь?**

Или: **Какая справедливость? О какой, к чёрту, справедливости речь?**

Для падежной формы (о справедливости) второй вариант более удобен с точки зрения интонации.

1) Обычно это усилительная частица.

**Из словаря:** Куда к чёрту; какой к чёрту. Употр. для усиления иронической или риторической интонации вопросительных местоимений и наречий, к которым относится. **Какой я к чёрту художник.**

Примеры:

В полнейшем восторге он пригласил ее в ресторан. **Какой к черту ресторан?** Здесь нет никаких ресторанов, одни столовки паршивые. [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)]

― Миша, о чем ты говоришь? **Какой к черту** Град Китеж? Это Интернационал-то? [А. Н. Толстой. Рукопись, найденная под кроватью (1923-1924)]

2) Но иногда встречаются **варианты с обособлением** (вводное слово или междометие, выражение чувства): Капитан сердито крикнул: ― **Какой, к черту, риф?** Здесь глубочайшая пучина океана! [И. А. Ефремов. Встреча над Тускаророй (1942-1943)]

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ,  Jasmin!